# Online Tools or Programatically determine web page links to other sites

Tags: web-crawler

What i want to do is i want to crawl one website example www.abc.com all pages and see if there are any instances of other domain code in all the pages. For example if the site has some reference to www.xyz.com then it should show that this page is refering some other urls /domains.

Want to use PHP, i have done research on it but all i can find is broken link checker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you using? What have you tried?

This comes down to two steps:

1. Fetch the web page. Many modern languages include libraries to do this, [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) in .NET, [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html) in python, [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/) in many languages including [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php), etc.
2. Search through the text of the page, searching for strings that match the pattern of a URL. Regular expressions rule here. In PHP you would use [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).